# Xcode 6 - No Visible interface for private members

Tags: class, nsmutablearray, switch-statement, let

I have declared private variables in implementation file of cycles.

myclass.m

```
@interface myclass()

@property (nonatomic) unsigned int number;

@end
```

Well, when I put in main.m something like this:

```
myclass * some = [[myclass alloc] init];

[some setNumber:10]; // no visible @interface for 'myclass' declares the selector 'setNumber'.

unsigned int a=[some getNumber]; //no visible @interface  ...
```

Every answer on StackOverflow.com points the same as I do. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the property **number** is a private property because you declared it in the interface section in your .m file. Declare it in your header myclass.h files interface block instead.. A **private** property, ivar, or method is one which can only be accessed from within an instance of your myClass object by using the self keyword (which is basically a pointer to the myClass instance within which you are currently executing).

Moving your property declaration to the header file will make the property accessible from outside the class instance. In other words, it makes it **public**.

---

If you want to restrict access to the data the property points to, define the property in the header file as a readonly property:

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, readonly) unsigned int number;

@end
```

Then in your .m file create a private ivar manually and override the getter for the number property as follows:

MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass {
    //Instance variable (ivar)
    unsigned int _number;   
}

unsigned int number()
{
    return _number;
}

@end
```

That way a subclass (or anyone else for that matter) can't muck with the value of number. You can then access number in your main function as follows:

```
MyClass* myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
unsigned int newNumber = myClass.number; //There is no such selector called getNumber BTW, only number.
```

Comment: Hmm, but  that way all subclasses will have access to that private variable. I want only instances of myclass to have access.

Comment: Updated answer... Is this kinda what you are looking for?

Comment: But I dont want it to be **PUBLIC**. I want it to be **private**. could you rewrite my code so I can see what you suggest. I dont understand.

Comment: @vladimir Are you creating a static or dynamic (.so) library?

Comment: @vladimir - sorry but you will have to expose a public property, or method to achieve your goal.

Comment: It wont work this way. "Use of undeclared identifier '_number'; did you mean 'number'. " error

Comment: I  just learn Objective-C. I have over 10 years C++ expirience.

Comment: I have been tried like you wrote but "Use of undeclared identifier '_number'..." error appears

Comment: you mean self._number? You can only access the _number private ivar from inside the the MyClass instance.. You must access via the self pointer.

Comment: I will try again all you suggest and read Objective-C big Nerd Ranch Guide further. When I get what I want I will come back here with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly/readwrite property definitions to achieve this.

**In MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *number;

@end
```

**In MyClass.m**

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSNumber *number;

@end
```

You can now read the `number` property outside of the class, and you will only be able to change it inside of MyClass.m. You can set it's value like so, `self.number = 5` inside of MyClass.m.

Objective-C does not have the same type of private variables that a language like Java has. What is it that you are trying to accomplish with a private variable?

Comment: Is there standard way for instance to access private member without declaring it at .h file?

Comment: I want to hide private variable from inheritance. EXAMPLE. Class Employee have accessCode. But class Person who is derived from class Employee cant have access to accessCode. I hope you understand me.

Comment: I think you have this backwards, Employee should be a subclass of Person... since an employee is first a person and then an employee. Create a `Person` class, and then create an `Employee` class. `Person` will not have access to any of `Employee`'s properties.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what if it must be like this. I learn Objective-C. I am C++ programmer and at C++ it is easy to hide inheritance but I would like to know how to do it with Objective-C without overriding methods, and without finding "other ways". I was hope there is one simple way that can be done like this.

Comment: You need to expose the property in the .h file in order to access it outside of the implementation file. The other way to access the property declared in your implementation file would be to create instance methods in the header file of your class.

Comment: But when I create instance methods in the header files, than derived classes have access again. I tried it right now.